# First time setting in seed nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I understood that seed node main purpose is to get the other nodes bootstrap into the cluster, apart from their is nothing important about except gossiping about the seeds for new nodes. I have read few installation documentation and would like to get clarified about the seed nodes for first time.

1) If the node has two seed nodes and two non seed nodes. For the first seed node when starting what should be the seeds list and auto boot strap values? Will it have the its own ip address and the second seed node ip address and auto-bootstrap: false?   Pls clarify on this, should I have the seed list here or not?

2) For non seed node , yes the seed list should be the first and second seeds ip address.

3) If I want to add another two seed nodes when I decide to have another data center seeds , I need to add that to the first data center seeds list and is restart necessary for this or it will automatically gossip with each other?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) If the node has two seed nodes and two non seed nodes. For the
>   first seed node when starting what should be the seeds list and auto
>   boot strap values? Will it have the its own ip address and the second
>   seed node ip address and auto-bootstrap: false? Pls clarify on this,
>   should I have the seed list here or not?

It's okay to have a node's own IP in the seed list.

> 2) For non seed node , yes the seed list should be the first and
>   second seeds ip address.

Right

> 3) If I want to add another two seed nodes when I decide to have
>   another data center seeds , I need to add that to the first data
>   center seeds list and is restart necessary for this or it will
>   automatically gossip with each other?

Seed lists do not get propagated via gossip. You should keep ~3 seed nodes per data center in the seed list and you have to rolling restart to pick it up.